# How to fill multiple input (type: color)

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, jscolor

I think this is a simple JS problem as I'm new to it.

I've created a bar chart using d3 along the lines of Scott Murray's example.

I want the user to select the colour of the bar chart using input id="cp". For this I'm using jscolor, which is working ok. When the user selects a colour, I have hardcoded the colour strength at 0.8 (minS:0.8), and set up three other inputs (type: color).

I want to set these three inputs to the same colour as "cp", but with reduced strengths (0.6, 0.4 & 0.2). This is so that my bar chart can colour its data by category.

It's working fine on page load:

```
<body onload="updateInfo('#3356FF')">
```

This works fine. It calls this js function:

```
function updateInfo(color) {

    var colA = "";

    svg.selectAll("rect")
        .attr("fill", color);

     if (typeof(color) === 'string' ) { 

        colA = color;

    } else {

        colA = String(color);
        colA = colA.toUpperCase();
        colA = "#" + colA;

    }


    var cpB = document.getElementById('cpB');
    cpB.value = colA;

    var cpC = document.getElementById('cpC');
    cpC.value = colA;

    var cpD = document.getElementById('cpD');
    cpD.value = colA;

}
```

This colours all the bars blue, in decreasing strengths, as intended. Here's the html with the inputs in. You can see the top input (id = 'cp') calls a function, updateInfo(this). "this" sends an object not a string, so you can see why the function above turns it back into a string.

```
<div class="col1">

    <input size="1px" id="cp" class="color {minS:0.8, onImmediateChange:'updateInfo(this);', pickerFace:20, slider:false, pickerFaceColor:'transparent', pickerFace:3, pickerBorder:0, pickerInsetColor:'white'}"  >
    <input class="cp_txt" value="Cat A" disabled>

    <input size="1px" id="cpB" class="color {maxS:0.6} cp_child" disabled >
    <input class="cp_txt" value="Cat B" disabled>

    <input size="1px" id="cpC" class="color {maxS:0.4} cp_child" disabled >     
    <input class="cp_txt" value="Cat C" disabled>

    <input size="1px" id="cpD" class="color {maxS:0.2} cp_child" disabled >
    <input class="cp_txt" value="Cat D" disabled>


</div>
```

I've checked using alerts and the code does run right the way to the end of the function even though the html inputs show no change in colour. I'm baffled because it works the first time round, and the new colour code is a string of 7 letters with a hash in capitals...

Can anyone help?

---- updated with jsfiddle ----

http://jsfiddle.net/dKyDY/1/

The jsfiddle example is giving a different result to my web editor (coda2) - and i think this might help identify the problem. Jsfiddle is throwing a problem every time an object rather than a string is passed to function updateInfo as a parameter.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you mean. Could you post a complete example please?

Comment: The closest I could get to was this: http://jsfiddle.net/tmLm8/ while porting it to `jsFiddle`.`jsColor` is sensitive to the order it is loaded w.r.t the DOM elements and it responds to `change` events only on pressing `Enter` on the box. Moreover, it doesn't seem that you can set `input.value` while setting the `maxS` on an input element. You will need [chroma](http://driven-by-data.net/about/chromajs/#/0), or something similar, to do that. Also, the order in which `svg.selectAll('rect').attr('fill', color)` was being called was wrong.

Comment: thanks for your comments. coda2 gives a different response (i.e. it recolours the bars) from jsfiddle and indeed from the live net. i appreciate the comments but still don't understand how to offer the color parameter in an acceptable form for the js function.